# Nested aggregations in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to implement autocomplete feature using elasticsearch. The  structure of the index which I am working on is this

```
"title": "blog post 1",
"body": "body of the blog post",
"category": "programming",
"locations": [
    {"name": "united states"}, 
    {"name": "new york"}, 
    {"name": "venice"}
]
```

I am trying to use nested aggregations. The mapping which I am using is this

```
{                            
  blog : {                   
    mappings : {             
      tag : {                
        properties : {       
          body : {           
            type : string    
          },                 
          category : {       
            type : string    
          },                 
          locations : {      
            properties : {   
              name : {       
                type : string
              }              
            }                
          },                 
          title : {          
            type : string    
          }                  
        }                    
      }                      
    }                        
  }                          
}
```

The query which is supposed to aggregate the results on the basis of `locations.name` is

```
GET /blog/tag/_search
{
    "size": 0, 
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "locations.name": "montreal"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "aggregated_locations": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "locations"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "filtered_locations": {
                   "terms": {
                      "fields": "locations.name"
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I am executing the above request using the chrome plugin for elasticsearch. The above query gives out an error, which is very long but I can post it too if someone prompts. I guess I might be wrong in interpreting the meaning of nested aggregations, which means my mapping is wrong. But I am not able to figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some missing parts in your mapping, you need to set the locations field to `nested` type and not analyzing the inner field to be able to aggregate with regards of your expectations:

```
PUT blog
{
  "mappings": {
    "tag": {
      "properties": {
        "body": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "category": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "locations": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then run following query to filter on nested field, and aggregate on nested field as well:

```
GET blog/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "locations",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "locations.name": "montreal"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "aggregated_locations": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "locations"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filtered": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "locations.name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Those query can be copied / pasted in sense (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/sense/current/installing.html)

Comment: I used --> `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/blog/_mapping/tag?pretty' >! test.json` to get the new mapping. But test.json is a huge file. It has many redundancies. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: So what I exactly did was deleted my index, ran the mapping, and then created the new index....is something wrong with my workflow? I am new to elasticsearch.

Comment: You can't update a mapping, the workflow is correct, you need to delete your index first. There is a blog post that explains it here (https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime) and also guide to do it with zero downtime.

Comment: The exact same mapping and query are not working in my chrome extension for sense. Is elasticsearch 2.0 required for using above specified queries and mappings, I am using elasticsearch 1.7 currently

Comment: The query returns all the elements in the locations list if it finds the particular location defined in the query. I just want the buckets to have only the single location which was queried